# G-WAN PHP servlet blocking with empty reply

Tags: php, http, g-wan, document-body

I send small payloads of various sizes as `"200"` replies but once in a while the payload is empty (no HTML body) and G-WAN takes a long time to answer those requests.

Can you tell me what's happening and how to resolve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why G-WAN took *"a long time"* to respond is because it expected a body from your PHP script.

As per the RFCs, `200` HTTP replies should not have an empty body.

You should rather use the `204` HTTP status code for when you must send an empty body.

In a PHP G-WAN script, this would be something like:

```
<?php
  exit(204); // return an HTTP code (204:'No Content')
?>
```

In a C G-WAN script, that will be:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   return 204;
}
```

As you see, reading the RFCs from time to time can help to remember that those guys have covered many useful cases.